# How to generate alert with "After Order Is Filled"

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have a strategy running with "after is filled" on and I would like to receive an alert when the condition is met. Even though the condition is met, the alert doesn't go through until the candle closes. I've tried using alert.freq_all option and the alert still goes through at candle close.

Does anyone have a way to get an alert to go through as soon as the condition is met?